# const annotation for Haskell FFI exports

Tags: c++, haskell, constants, ffi

I am exposing a Haskell function to C/C++ as

```
foreign export ccall foo :: Ptr CInt -> CInt -> IO CInt

foo ptr len = do
  list <- peekArray (fromIntegral len) ptr
  -- run calculation based on list entries
  return result
```

The signature of the exported function becomes

```
HsInt32 foo(HsPtr a1, HsInt32 a2);
```

However, since the array is not being modified, I would rather have this as

```
HsInt32 foo(const HsPtr a1, HsInt32 a2);
```

Is there a way to automatically add this annotation?

(The motivation is that I want this to operate on an std::vector< int > via

```
inline int foo(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
  return foo(v.data(), v.size());
}
```

without including a const_cast.)

Comment: Try changing the function signature in header file with `extern "C" HsInt32 foo(const HsPtr a1, HsInt32 a2);` manually.

Comment: That would give the desired result.  However, since I am generating the header stubs as part of my make infrastructure, I'd rather have a way to specify the annotation directly in the .hs file.

Comment: It really is annoying that we can't have proper const-pointers in FFI declarations. In Haskell! Have you considered filing a feature request on [the GHC Trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no facility in GHC for generating the C helper function with `const` annotations.  In particular, the relevant code in the GHC source is in `compiler/deSugar/DsForeign.hs` function `mkFExportCBits` which generates the C stub.  Each argument is given an unadorned C type consisting of the prefix "Hs" and the name of the constructor.  There's no way to add a `const` in there anywhere.

There's not even a hope of getting GHC to use a user-defined C type, like `HsConstPtr` that you could use:  the permitted types for foreign arguments are restricted to those determined by the `boxedMarshalableTyCon` function in `compiler/typecheck/TcType.hs` (with associated definitions of the C types in `includes/HsFFI.h`).

On the other hand, it's not clear why you can't just cast away the const in the wrapper you're writing anyway:

```
inline int foo_wrapper(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
  std::vector<int> &v2 = const_cast<std::vector <int>&>(v);
  return foo_haskell(v2.data(), v2.size());
}
```

If that makes you feel dirty... well, programming is a dirty business, right?

Comment: Was `v2` meant to be `pv`, or vice versa?

Comment: Thanks!  It should be fixed now.

Comment: Indeed, I dislike the dirty const_cast, but I hid it now in a HaskellPointer() wrapper function. My hope is that perhaps in the future this could be removed -- at least naïvely I'd think that having something like a "ConstPtr a" type might be useful also for optimization purposes.  For now, thanks for digging up that currently there's no way to add the annotation on the Haskell side!